# How to configure Tomcat to only listen to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, localhost, tomcat6

The environment is Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS running Tomcat 6 and Apache 2.2 from the repos. Apache is configured to proxy requests to Tomcat, so I really want to turn off Tomcat listening to requests on external IP addresses.

I found out how to change the port number in /etc/tomcat6/server.xml with the Connector tag, but this isn't what I need.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Inside the file `server.xml` (or similar) you should have the `Service` tag. Change this from:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
...
```

to:

```xml
<Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
...
```

In this way it should not bind anymore on `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces) but just on your loopback interface. For more information:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html